# Gridview Image Displaying in IE But Not In Firefox and Chrome

Tags: asp.net, gridview

My Code:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" Imageurl='<%# "\\machine-17\temp\test1.jpg" %>' runat="server"/>
```

I tried ~,\,/ but not working...

`\\machine-17\temp\test.jpg` - This path come from Database(SqlServer)

Comment: please share full code. It is very difficult to answer this way

Comment: The `machine-17` folder exists inside the root of the website?

Comment: Out of 15 Machines user save images from the network. The machine-17 change dynamically...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i copied those images into my local and make it work.